# pcl_ros manifest.xml changes

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the diamondback , pcl_ros's manifest.xml says

```
 <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include -I${prefix}/msg_gen/cpp/include -I${prefix}/cfg/cpp" lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -lpcl_ros_io -lpcl_ros_features -lpcl_ros_filters -lpcl_ros_segmentation -lpcl_ros_surface -lpcl_ros_tf"/>
```

In the electric , pcl_ros's manifest.xml says

```
 <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include -I${prefix}/cfg/cpp" lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -lpcl_ros_tf" /> `
```

and the former flag options were uncommented.
I wonder why it had changed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11549/pcl_ros-manifest.xml-changes/) by [chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/510/chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `-I${prefix}/msg_gen/cpp/include` is no longer needed (and deprecated).

I don't know about the `-l` linker parameters.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0